# What is what is mp4.lvix file extension, and can I safely delete it?

Tags: video, mp4

In a directory with some important files and some junk files, I see a file with extension `MP4.lvix`. I don't recall directly creating this file (so I assume a program created it somewhere along the line).

The layperson's question I have is: 'what is it and can I delete it? (without adverse consequences)'.

I checked the file size and it's very small (<250 bytes). So an educated guess may be that it's not a video file, but possibly metadata. I don't know anything else about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a metadata file that the Lightworks video editing package produces (https://www.lwks.com).

It is used for faster access to some video files, AFAIK, and is in addition to your original video file, not replacing it.

Unless you are using this software still it sounds like you don't need it.

If you are using the software and want to avoid clutter there is some discussion on the Lightworks forum around this:

- https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=27&id=214160&Itemid=81

Comment: Weirdly enough, found myself back here via a google search for the same questions (again). I can confirm that they can be deleted without any problems.